# Managed Identity Authentication from non Azure VM

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk, azure-identity

I would like to access from a Java application to an Azure Key Vault.I would like to use Managed Authentication.
If I understand correctly this solution is only available using VM on Azure and is not possible on a server outside the Microsoft environment. In this case I would have to proceed with access via clientId, tenantId and secret using ClientSecretCredential.
Did I understand correctly or is it possible to use Managed Identity Authentication also on machines outside Azure?

Here some sources:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-storage-blob_12.16.1/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#authenticating-service-principals

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Azure-Identity-Examples#authenticating-in-azure-with-managed-identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case I would have to proceed with access via `clientId`, `tenantId` and `secret` using `ClientSecretCredential`. Did I understand correctly or is it possible to use Managed Identity Authentication also on machines outside Azure?

Yes, you will still need environment variables like `clientID`, `tentantID` and `SecretClient` with `DefaultAzureCredential` and `EnvironmentCredential`.

For example, you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.identitydigest.com/azuread-access-aws/) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61881941/15969115) on how to use Azure Managed Identity to access resources of other cloud provider.